# Environment variables undefined in NextJS when running Jest

Tags: jestjs, environment-variables, next.js

I have a simple NextJS project set up, and am having problems getting Jest to recognize my environment variables. I've followed the instructions on https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#test-environment-variables to the best of my abilities, but can't get it to work.

Here is a simplfied version of my problem.

```
// .env.test.local
MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=my_value
```

```js
// My function I want to test
export const getEnvironment = () => {
  const MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = process.env.MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE;
  return MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE;
};
```

```js
// My test
import { getEnvironment } from './getEnvironment';

describe('Get environment', () => {
  it('will have the correct environment variable', () => {
    const myEnvironmentVar = getEnvironment();
    const expectedEnv = "my_value";
    expect(myEnvironmentVar).toEqual(expectedEnv);
  });
});
```

I'm running jest with `jest --watch`. I can see that it gets environment `test`, but none of my own specified variables show up.

The test above fails with

```
Expected: "my_value"
Received: undefined
```

If any additional files have relevance, please comment and I'll add what I have.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### NextJS 12 with new compiler SWC

NextJS version 12 introduced a new compiler, SWC, written in Rust. Managing environment variables with this compiler is really easy and built in. The documentation at https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#jest describes how to set up your Jest configuration:

```
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

// Providing the path to your Next.js app which will enable loading next.config.js and .env files
const createJestConfig = nextJest({ dir: './' });

// Any custom config you want to pass to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', __dirname]
};

// createJestConfig is exported in this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js configuration, which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

Here I've added a custom config for `moduleDirectories` since I had problems with absolute imports when running tests. Since my code resides in `.` I wanted to add `'.'` as a module directory. But due to an [open bug in Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12889) you have to specify `__dirname` instead.

### NextJS 11 and earlier

Since I asked this question, the documentation has been updated and provided a better answer than starting next fully before the tests.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#test-environment-variables

The proposed way of loading environment variables into your testing environment is to add a config file for jest, add a setup script, and in that script use NextJS included `loadEnvConfig` function.

The `.env.test` can be filled with dummy data and checked into your repo. As with normal environment variables, you can override them locally with a `.env.test.local`-file.

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/__test__/setupEnv.js'
}
```

```
// __test__/setupEnv.js
import { loadEnvConfig } from '@next/env'

export default async () => {
  const projectDir = process.cwd()
  loadEnvConfig(projectDir)
}
```

```
# .env.test
MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE="a-variable-for-testing"
```

Answer (score 7):

Next needs to have been instantiated before your test is run in order to have access to these environment variables.

```js
    // include this in your Jest setup file, or before your tests
    import next from "next";
    next({});
```

There's currently a pull request to add this to the Next documentation: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/16443

Make sure to also respect the naming convention for [client-side environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser), prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` if the environment variable will be used in client-facing code.

Comment: Great, that worked! And thanks for the link to the PR. I encountered a new problem which was easy to solve. I'll add it to your answer for completeness sake. And welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: The problem I mentioned in the above comment has been fixed in the question instead of this answer to align with editing rules for answers!

Comment: need to use `next({ dev: true })`

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me. I just literally loaded in my environment variables through `dotenv` in the jest config file. I think probably because the environment file is called `.env.local` (which might be different than what next js uses by default)

```js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
    dir: './',
});

dotenv.config({path: '.env.local'});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', __dirname],
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js']
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```